# Safari on OSX keep showing mobile version

Tags: macos, mobile, responsive-design, safari

My website under OSX macbook is showing only the mobile version of the website : [WebSite](http://www.lpfilmfest.org)

So i check the website : www.lpfilmfest.org on windows under Safari and there is no problem but on Safari under OSX i still have the mobile version of the website.

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance

chris

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that with this below it works :

```
html, body {height:100%;overflow:auto} 
aside {min-height:700px;height:auto} /* which is the container for sidebar which could be Fixed position on desktop and notebook computer - line 166
```